# freopen and fwprintf writes incorrect wide characters into TXT file

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I've already spent the whole day searching for an answer about UTF-8 and UTF-16 options when freopen and fwprintf used and no results for now. I will add my code below, maybe someone can help. Thanks in advance.

```
template<typename... ArgsT>
void log(const wchar_t* message, ArgsT... args)
{
    fwprintf(stdout, message, args...);
    fwprintf(stdout, L"\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main()
{
    bool init = true;
    if (!std::freopen("log.txt", "w", stdout))
    {
        init = false;
    }

    if (std::fwide(stdout, 1) <= 0)
    {
        init = false;
    }

    if (init)
    {
        std::wstring str = L"кирилиця";
        log(L"Some text in cyrillic %S and some number %i", str.c_str(), 10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As the result in TXT file I have: Some text in cyrillic :8@8;8FO and some number 10

Comment: When you write non-ASCII quoted string literals in your code like this: `L"кирилиця";` it is not guaranteed that what you end up with is what you expect.  Use the debugger to inspect what that `str` really has inside of it.

Comment: Try changing mode to "wb" and print format to "%ls".

Comment: Since when does C have `std::wstring`?

Comment: Thanks, Johnny Mopp, it helped. Can you please, explain a bit?

Comment: According to [MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx), re `l` or `w`: _Wide-character string with printf and wprintf functions. (An ls, lS, ws or wS type specifier is synonymous with S in printf functions and with s in wprintf functions.)_

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your file with wchar_t(0xFEFF).
It tells text editor apps to treat following data as unicode.